# Chrome seems to use different DNS than IE 11--is this possible?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, internet-explorer

I know the question sounds odd.  I have both Chrome and IE11.  Google is homepage on both.  On a fairly regular basis I will type in a search term and Chrome will just hang, usually ending up in some sort of  "DNS not resolved" or some error with the google sad-face--but sometimes the site does appear but after a good 20 seconds or so.

I will then immediately copy the identical search term into IE 11 and it hits instantly.  Back to Chrome, another hang for the exact same term.  Other sites come up fine in Chrome so it's not a fundamental problem with Chrome itself.

This is plain bizarre.  When it happens my first thought is "darn, my internet must be down".  But I go to IE11 and everything is humming along fine.

I'm convinced that somehow Chrome ignores my router's DNS.  I'm hoping someone here can at least offer some insight.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear/flush the DNS cache in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)

Comment: *Usually* Chrome works and IE is FUBAR ;-p

Comment: just in the generic sense, it is possible for any program to control the means by which address lookups are performed, especially when the maker of the software has a global DNS service in their possession.

Comment: @DavidPostill the info in that link looks very promising, I will let this thread know the results.  It is exactly the kind of thing I expected to find--that Chrome has it's own DNS cache.   Since the problem is sporadic I won't know for a week or so (I've never gone a week without it happening)  Thanks!

Comment: [Does Chrome use a different DNS server from the OS?](http://superuser.com/q/656938/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Chrome use a different DNS server from Firefox and IE which use the OS default?](http://superuser.com/questions/65382/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-firefox-and-ie-which-use-the-os-defa)