# Google Chrome wrong dns resolves

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I'm experiencing this strange issue:

Google Chrome is resolving [paypalobjects.com](http://paypalobjects.com) in a wrong ip

I did these operations without success:

- clear/flush chrome brosing cache
- clear/flush chrome dns cache
- clear/flush chrome socket cache
- /flush pc dns cache `ipconfig /flushdns`

this problem is avoiding me to use paypal..

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Chrome use a different DNS server from the OS?](http://superuser.com/questions/656938/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-the-os?rq=1), [How to clear/flush the DNS cache in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 did you read the comments on the answer you are pointing?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @ChrisM after some time it solved

Comment: I fixed mine as well.  for some reason, my router's dynamic dns setting wasn't picking up the new ip address after 2 full days.  I set my network card to centurylink's static dns addresses and it worked immediately.  Still weird that only Chrome wouldn't update my new ip when other browsers on the same network card/settings updated almost immediately.