# DNS lookup fails in chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser, linux-mint, browser-cache

Trying to access certain sites fails in Google Chrome only:

[image]

**ping** goes through OK:

[image]

**nslookup** is OK:

[image]

**Firefox** loads the page OK

- Changing between WiFi and wired network has no effect
- Using one of Google DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) has no effect
- Chrome browser cache is cleared
- Chrome host cache is cleared

Additional info:

- Running Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
- Linux Mint 18.2 Sonia (64-bit) Cinnamon

Other websites impacted:

- Google Docs
- Google Drive
- And many many more, but not all. Youtube, Google and Gmail work ok

Comment: Try checking "Chrome-internals", such as:  chrome://net-internals/#dns | Also, check how Chrome uses DNS on Mint/Linux. See ( https://superuser.com/questions/656938/does-chrome-use-a-different-dns-server-from-the-os ).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using private DNS (over HTTPS) with chrome, as this might be the root cause of your issue.

```
chrome://settings/security?search=use+secure+dns
```

[image: secure DNS]

If it is enabled, you can try to disable it or try a different provider!